# Passar Objetos da JSP com Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Caros,

Tenho as classes abaixo.

Estou com problema na hora de criar uma ArvoreClassificacao, pois na JSP estou passando os parâmetros "Id Area" e "Descricao Arvore", no controller estou recebendo um objeto AreaArvoreClassificacao (aac), que possui as outras classes nele, só que estão vindo **nulos**.

O mapeamento das classes estão errados?

Obs: No banco de dados, a Tabela Area e ArvoreClassificacao, possui um relacionamento N para N, portanto possuem uma tabela associativa entre elas, que se chama AreaArvoreClassificacao.

AreaArvoreClassificacao:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="areas_has_arvore_classificacao")
public class AreaArvoreClassificacao {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="area_id")
    private Area area;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="arvore_classificacao_id")
    private ArvoreClassificacao arvoreClassificacao;

}
```

Area:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="area")
public class Area {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="descricao")
    @Size(max=100)
    private String descricao;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="status")
    private String status;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }



}
```

ArvoreClassificacao

```
@Entity
@Table(name="arvore_classificacao")
public class ArvoreClassificacao {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name="id")
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="descricao")
    private String descricao;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="status")
    private String status;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }



}
```

Parte da JSP:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                <!--  INCLUIR O SELECT QUE IRA LISTAR AS ÁREAS -->
                <label for="area.id">Escolha a área:</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="Area.id" id="area.id" required>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <c:forEach var="area" items="${areas }">
                        <option value="${area.id }">${area.descricao }</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                <label for="arvoreClassificacao.descricao">Descrição Arvore:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="ArvoreClassificacao.descricao" id="arvoreClassificacao.descricao" class="form-control" placeholder="Exemplo: Conhecimento - Cancelou serviço indevidamente" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btnForm btn-lg btn-block">Criar!</button>
            </div>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping("CriarArvoreClassificacao")
    public String criarArvore(Model model, AreaArvoreClassificacao aac) throws IOException{
        // DEBUGAR PARA VER O QUE TA CHEGANDO OU SE TA CHEGANDO ALGO
        System.out.println(aac);
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido já.

Implementei os gets e sets na classe AreaArvoreClassificacao e alterei os "names" na JSP para que corresponder as classes.